# NodeJS Ajax request fails

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I have an form I am trying to submit from client to Express but every time I get an error like:

> Cannot POST /request_method

Below are the code which I am trying:

> index.html

```
<form id="wizard-content" method="post">
   <label>File</label>
   <input type="file" name="some" id="rsome">
   <label>Value</label>
   <input type="text" name="valSome" id="perfect">
</form>
<button type="submit" id="submit_form">Finish</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#submit_form').click(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).text().toLowerCase() === "finish") {
                submitForm();
            }
        });
        var submitForm = function(){
            var formData = {
                    'perfect'        : $('#perfect').val(),
                    'rsome'            : $('#rsome')[0].files[0]
                };
            if(formData){
                $.ajax({
                    url : '/request_method',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : formData,
                    contentType : false,
                    cache : false,
                    processData: false,
                    success : function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }, 
                    error : function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And in expressJs :

> server.js

```
var express     = require('express');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser());
.
.
router.post('/request_method', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.ip);
});
```

Comment: Put the entire URL name..eg.localhost:5000/xxxx

Comment: Any other error info? What status is the response (e.g. check in devtools)

Comment: @ovidiuDolha I am not getting any other error, this is the one and I get 404 response.

Comment: @sabareesh I have tried with the (window.location.origin+method_name) still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `app` is probably not using the `router` you have ceated.

## Two solutions

**1 - Define the route by using your app and not your router**

```
app.post('/request_method', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.ip);
});
```

**2 - Or using your router**

Add the following line before the `router.post...` which will tell your application to use the routes that are defined in your `router`.

```
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: I have made a very silly mistake, I have not created the router for this particular URL. Thanks dude. It worked.

Comment: Feel free to accept my post as the answer if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should include bodyParser like that,

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

or

```
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var submitForm = function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('#wizard-content')[0]);
    if(formData){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/request_method',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            contentType : false,
            cache : false,
            processData: false,
            success : function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }, 
            error : function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At you route, use `req.files[0]` to get the file input

Answer (score -1):

I have made a very silly mistake, I have forget to add the URL using router.

```
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: There is no need to post answer yourself if someone had already give you satisfactory answer. Just accept his answer and that's enough. :)